# gcc:linker: set section size to 8 bytes

Tags: gcc, linker, verilog, objcopy

I am running `arm-none-eabi-objcopy  -O verilog -S --reverse-bytes=4 --verilog-data-width 8 -R .comment --gap-fill 0 --pad-to 0x2000 bin/main.elf bin/main.verilog`

To convert my code in a format suitable for loading in simulation memory via readmemh
The generated hexfile has sections that are not multiple of 8 bytes resulting in the main.verilog containing

```
0000805800008068 0000230105FFFF01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
04000008                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
@000002C4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
000002D000002000 00000000
```

How do I ensure that instead of `04000008` the main.verilog file has `0000000004000008`

Comment: BFD verilog seems to be under-documented.  See https://github.com/sifive/elf2hex.  This is the patchset and issue tracker that included this feature.

Comment: Opps, here is the link. https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19921  I would try with some other sizes first.  You can use `{ high32, low32 }` to  make a wired index.  It is probably slightly in-efficient, but I am not sure if you want this for simulation or synthesis.  My first thought was to process with awk/sed as the `readmemh()` is extremely simple format.  But `objcopy` does have the verilog backend, so it may work.